# Usercake PHP user management system bug: outputs path on top of directory overview

Tags: php, usercake

I'm using a mod of the usercake usermanagement system.
Usercake: http://usercake.com/
Mod: http://usercake.com/thread.php?id=366
The mod makes it possible to protect files in subfolders. This is the source for the directory overview (admin_pages.php):

```
<?php
/*
UserCake Version: 2.0.2
http://usercake.com
*/
$root=str_replace('\\','/',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once("models/config.php");
if (!securePage($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){die();}
$path="";
if(isset($_GET['path'])) $path=$_GET['path'];

$script=dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$baspth=$path;
$dir = glob($root.$path."/*" ,GLOB_ONLYDIR);


$pages = getPageFiles($root.$path); //Retrieve list of pages in root usercake folder
$dbpages = fetchAllPages(); //Retrieve list of pages in pages table
$creations = array();
$deletions = array();

//Check if any pages exist which are not in DB
if (count($pages) > 0)
foreach ($pages as $page){
    if(!isset($dbpages[$page])){
        $creations[] = $page;   
    }
}

//Enter new pages in DB if found
if (count($creations) > 0) {
    createPages($creations) ;
}

if (count($dbpages) > 0){
    //Check if DB contains pages that don't exist
    foreach ($dbpages as $page){
        if(!isset($pages[$page['page']])){
            $deletions[] = $page['id']; 
        }
    }
}

//Delete pages from DB if not found
/*if (count($deletions) > 0) {
    deletePages($deletions);
}*/

//Update DB pages
$dbpages = fetchAllPagesD($path."/");

require_once("models/header.php");

echo "
<body>
<div id='wrapper'>
<div id='content'>
<h1>Nutzermanagement</h1>
<h2>Admin Pages</h2>
<div id='left-nav'>";

include("left-nav.php");



echo "
</div>
<div id='main'>
<table class='admin'>
<tr><th><h2>".$baspth."/</h2></th></tr>
<tr><td style='padding-right:25px;'><table class='admin'  width='300'>
<tr><th>Id</th><th align='left'>Page</th><th>Access</th></tr>
";


//Display list of pages
if (count($dbpages) > 0)
foreach ($dbpages as $page){

    echo "
    <tr>
    <td>
    ".$page['id']."
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href ='admin_page.php?id=".$page['id']."'>".basename($page['page'])."</a>
    </td>
    <td>";

    //Show public/private setting of page
    if($page['private'] == 0){
        echo "Public";
    }
    else {
        echo "Private"; 
    }

    echo "
    </td>
    </tr>";
}
else echo "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>";
echo "</table></td>
<td style='padding-left:40px;border-left:1px solid'><table class='admin'>
<tr><th align='left'>Directories</th></tr>
";
//echo"<br>realpth:".$realpth." baspth:".$baspth." dirname (baspth):".dirname($baspth)."<br>";

if($path!="/" )
{
    $top=dirname($baspth);
    if($top=="\\")$top="";
    echo "<tr><td><a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?path=".$top."'>../</a></tr></td>";
}
if (count($dir) > 0)
foreach ($dir as $directory){
$directory =str_replace($root,'',$directory);
    echo "
    <tr>
    <td>
        ";

            echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?path=".$directory."'>".basename($directory)."</a>";



    echo "
    </td>
    </tr>";
}
echo "</table></td></tr>";
echo "
</table>
</div>
<div id='bottom'></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>";

?>
```

The problem is, that the code ALWAYS returns the actual path on the very top of the page, before every other code. That means, if I check the source with the browser it displays e.g.:

```
1 /folder/
```

And I can't find the location in the source code which creates this first line. Any idea?

Comment: Search for the **getcwd()** command

Comment: Thank's for the advice but there's no such command in none of usercake's files.